# Sencha Theming with Compass and Sass not working

Tags: sass, compass-sass, sencha-touch-theming

I am trying to build a custom theme. I added the $base-color and $base_gradient properties to my resources/sass/app.scss and compiled it by issuing compass compile from the folder. The compilation worked and replaced the css/app.csss. However I am not seeing the changes reflected in my application. How do I change the theme with sass and compass?

Answer (score 0):

Base gradient takes a - not a _

Then check that your var are defined after the line (should not matter for base-color but better to put them after)

```
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';
```

Your vars should be defined like this :

```
$base-color: #7A1E08;  
$base-gradient: 'glossy';
```

Check that you are in the [app-folder]/resources/sass/app.css and not in the sdk folder

When compiling you should see the following line

```
overwrite ../css/app.css
```

Empty your browser cache then reload your app.

Comment: I have found that I have to define $base-color before the first import or it will have no effect.

@Ronan Does it work for you if you define it after the import?

Comment: I put my vars after 
_import 'sencha-touch/default/all'_; 
and before
_include sencha-panel_;

Comment: Check this post for more explanations [link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?238064-SASS-Form-variable-form-label-background-color)